# How To Call Array from other File

Tags: php, arrays

i have  a array from oher file php and show in select data html

this is my array

**array.php**

```
<?php
    $category_attachment = array(       "SPK" ,    
                                        "Justifikasi" ,  
                                        "PR" ,  
                                        "RAB" ,  
                                        "Proc" ,  
                                        "PO" ,  
                                        "Notulen" ,  
                                        "Sertifikat" ,  
                                        "BAUT" ,  
                                        "BAST" ,  
                                        "Tagihan" ,
                                        "Other"
                                ); ?>
```

and this **myfile.php**

```
<?php include "array.php" ?>

<select name="category" id="category">
<option value="">Choose Category</option>
  // I want array data in here
</select>
```

Help Me Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<select name="category" id="category">
    <option value="">Choose Category</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($category_attachment as $value) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: @MuhamadRidwansyah happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

just try `print_r($category_attachment);` in your `myfile.php` and see what happens. you should be able to access the variable after you included the file

Also, you should disable the first option by using the `disabled` attribute ;)

```
<?php 
    include "array.php" 
    print_r($category_attacment);
?>

<select name="category" id="category">
    <option disabled>Choose Category</option>
<?php
foreach($category_attachment as $cat) { 
    echo "<option value='" . $cat . "'>" . $cat . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

**This example won't work:**

```
<?php 
    print_r($category_attacment);
    include "array.php" 
?>
```

you have to include the file before you can access the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following :

```
<select name="category" id="category">
<option value="">Choose Category</option>
    <?php
      foreach($category_attachment as $category){
      echo '<option value="'.$category'">'.$category.'</option>'; 
     }
     ?>
</select>
```

Give a look at foreach doc, which is very useful when using array :

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
<?php include "array.php" ?>
<select name="category" id="category">
    <option value="">Choose Category</option>
    <?php foreach ($category_attachment as $category) {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category; ?>"><?php echo $category; ?></option>  
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this,

```
<select name="category" id="category">
    <?php
    foreach ($category_attachment as $value) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?= $value ?>"><?= $value ?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```